# Gcloud can't work with git

Tags: git, gcloud

I was beginner, it's my first step with gcloup and git
I'm working on Windows 7 64 bits, i have install Gcloud SDK, and Git 1.9.4
In google developper consol I have create an application.
In my computer I have create an application "Hello World" in PHP.
When I try to upload the application in google cloud in commande line :

```
gcloud init cogent-array-677
```

And the result is

> E:\GOOGLE>gcloud init cogent-array-677 Initialized gcloud directory in
>   [E:\GOOGLE\cogent-array-677.gcloud]. Cloning
>   [https://source.developers.google.com/p/cogent-array-677/r/default]
>   into  [default]. ERROR: Unable to initialize project
>   [cogent-array-677], cleaning up [E:\GOOGLE\c ogent-array-677]. ERROR:
>   (gcloud.init) Cannot find git. Please install git and try again.
>
> You can find git installers at [http://git-scm.com/downloads], or use
>   your favorite package manager to install it on your computer.

I have git commande line and git gui.

Regard.

Answer (score 3):

I have juste to reboot the computer for the environnement var in windows. 
Git run perfectly with Gcloud.

Regards.